# get custom attribute value in php

Tags: php, attributes

I am try to get the value of the input field with a custom attribute I have created using PHP. This is my code:

```
<form action="uploadform.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" mynewattribute="myemail">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

//uploadform.php
<?php
//I know $name = $_POST['email']; will give me the value but I would like to get the value of the input field with "mynewattribute" and not name. Is it possible?
?>
```

Comment: You could use some frontend library (or raw JavaScript) to post custom attributes, standard way does not allows you to have custom attributes in $_POST array. Besides if you post the form as in your example you will get something like $_POST['email'] and not $_POST['name']

Comment: you want `mynewattribute= “the value entered in form”` ?

Comment: @DevStan , can i do this with get method ?

Comment: @Sebastian it does not matter which method you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web browser doesn't know what to do with your custom attribute, so will simply ignore it. The only data sent when you submit the form is the values of "successful" elements. So your custom data will never be sent, and can never be read by the receiving script.

The best place to put such data is into hidden input fields. One possibility is to use names with square brackets in, which PHP automatically converts into arrays. e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="email[value]">
<input type="hidden" name="email[magic]" value="true">
```

Populates an array like this:

```
$_POST['email']['value'] = '';
$_POST['email']['magic'] = 'true';
```